# Retrieving data from DB adding it to arrayList Count Issue

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Hi am using a query to retrieve data from DB based on creationDate & adding it to an arrayList to have some filter logic . while printing the size of ArrayList on console, **if records count is less than 50000 its giving proper value but if more than 50000 its giving 50000 as default value** , am unable to trace out problem as far my knowledge arrayList has limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE . then why am getting this issue ?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Also please paste your query and the database you are using.

Comment: In addition, do you really _want_ to deal with a result set so large?  You might really want to use some pagination here.  Most databases support pagination.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help but i guess i got the clue for it DB personal have set the limit for 50000 as i can see in QueryEngine which we are using it as a template to fetch the records from DB . Again thanks for the help highly appreciated..!!

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen we have the requirement as our product is generating this much data .

Comment: @Ansuman OK...but again, do you have to read it all at once?  I would feel much safer reading in batches.  Imagine trying to read 100K records in one go, and at record 199.999K something goes wrong and you have to start all over again.

Comment: Yah @TimBiegeleisen sure i'll keep that in mind .